# How to use debounce with Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to `debounce` a method within a Vuex action that requires an external API.

```
// Vuex action:

async load ({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
  const params = {
    period: state.option.period,
    from: state.option.from,
    to: state.option.to
  }

  commit('SET_EVENTS_LOADING', true)
  const res = loadDebounced.bind(this)
  const data = await res(params)
  console.log(data)


  commit('SET_EVENTS', data.collection)
  commit('SET_PAGINATION', data.pagination)
  commit('SET_EVENTS_LOADING', false)

  return data
}



// Debounced method

const loadDebounced = () => {

  return debounce(async (params) => {
    const { data } = await this.$axios.get('events', { params })
    return data
  }, 3000)

}
```

The output of the log is:

```
[Function] {                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  cancel: [Function]
}
```

It is not actually executing the debounced function, but returning to me another function.

Comment: Also what is the implementation of `debounce`? Are you using a library?

Comment: Does https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-chebyshev-i4824 help? If it does, I'll post an answer. Setting up actions  and using the `debounce` library is a tedious task and it is already 1AM here

Comment: @AlexMA Underscore.js

Comment: @Saksham I want to prevent rapid API calls.

Comment: I used to work on debouncing switches for the Intel 8085 Processor … Perhaps this has a similar context?

Comment: @Michael I'd debounce in a different place, I think you should setup debounce before `load()`. Can you give more context where `load()` method is fired and why do you want to debounce it?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present a custom debounce method which you can use in your vuex store as

```
let ongoingRequest = undefined;
const loadDebounced = () => {
    clearTimeout(ongoingRequest);
    ongoingRequest = setTimeout(_ => {
        axios.get(<<your URL>>).then(({ data }) => data);
    }, 3000);
}
```

This method first ensures to cancel any ongoing `setTimeout` in the pipeline and then executes it again.

This can be seen in action [HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-debounce-i4824)